# Pyinstaller not working for package (pyreadstat)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I always have used pyinstaller to create executables files but now when on working on a older project I am facing some issues. 
I have figured out that the main problem is while importing pyreadstat package. (pyreadstat is a python package to read spss files.)

```
import pyreadstat
```

Post running pyinstaller it first gives error for Module not found pandas. To resolve this I added --hidden-import pandas then it gave another error about Module not found pyreadstat._readstat_writer.
Once I added that as hidden import I got Module not found worker.

I am now not sure why pyinstaller is behaving in this way. Earlier it used to work correctly.

Can someone provider their input here. Below is the cmd log for reference.

```
D:\Projects\Test>pyinstaller --onefile test.py
62 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
62 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
62 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
62 INFO: wrote D:\Projects\Test\test.spec
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
69 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\Projects\\Test', 'D:\\Projects\\Test']
69 INFO: checking Analysis
69 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
69 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
69 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
85 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1941 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
1941 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib'
3458 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3552 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3552 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\program files\python39\python.exe
3599 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files\python39\python39.dll
3615 INFO: Analyzing D:\Projects\Test\test.py
3630 INFO: Processing module hooks...
3630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3630 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
3630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3630 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
3630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3703 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3703 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
3703 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3828 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3828 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util
3828 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util
3844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3844 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
3844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3891 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4006 INFO: checking Tree
4006 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
4021 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
4085 INFO: checking Tree
4085 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
4085 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
4180 INFO: checking Tree
4180 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
4180 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
4196 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4211 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4211 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
4211 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4446 INFO: Looking for eggs
4446 INFO: Using Python library c:\program files\python39\python39.dll
4446 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
4446 INFO: Warnings written to D:\Projects\Test\build\test\warn-test.txt
4477 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\Projects\Test\build\test\xref-test.html
4524 INFO: checking PYZ
4524 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
4524 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\Projects\Test\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
4883 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\Projects\Test\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
4899 INFO: checking PKG
4899 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
4899 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
6528 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
6528 INFO: Bootloader c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
6528 INFO: checking EXE
6528 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
6528 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
6528 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\Projects\Test\dist\test.exe
6700 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

D:\Projects\Test>cd dist

D:\Projects\Test\dist>test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pyreadstat\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "pyreadstat\pyreadstat.pyx", line 1, in init pyreadstat.pyreadstat
  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 28, in init pyreadstat._readstat_parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[10584] Failed to execute script test
```

Comment: Does you test.py script just run collectly?

Comment: Why not to install pandas instead of adding --hidden-import pandas to resolve this.

Comment: Yes the original python script runs fine. pandas, pyreadstat and all other packages are already installed.

Comment: How about to check if there two version python? Like there's pandas in python2, but pyinstaller in python3.9?

Comment: Was not able to any such versions for python 3.9

Comment: I actually have the exact same issue. My Python script works just fine but not when I package it with `pyinstaller main.py --clean --noconfirm --hidden-import pyreadstat`